# Turn this string: “ab1_cd2_ef3.php” into 3 variables: “ab1”, "cd2" and “ef3”?

Tags: php, string

I have a file name that holds three values, these values are separated by an underscore.

An example of the file name could be:

`/ab1_cd2_ef3.php`

Now, what i would like to do is capture the values held within the file name and turn them into local variables, so i could have:

```
$var1 = 'ab1';
$var2 = 'cd2';
$var3 = 'ef3';
```

So essentially:

```
$filename = basename(__FILE__, ".php");

miracleFunction($fileName);

var_dump($miracleFunctionVars);
// Be be maybe an array like
$miracleFunctionVar[1] = 'ab1';
$miracleFunctionVar[2] = 'cd2';
$miracleFunctionVar[3] = 'ef3';
```

Comment: `list($var1,$var2,$var3) = explode('_',pathinfo($mystring,PATHINFO_FILENAME));`

Comment: @MarkBaker That is a really useful approach, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
$filename      = basename(__FILE__, ".php"); //"ab1_cd2_ef3" basename removes ext
$splitfilename = explode('_', $filename);
```

Resulting in:

```
$splitfilename[0] = "ab1";
$splitfilename[1] = "cd2";
$splitfilename[2] = "ef3";
```

`explode` splits strings by a delimiter into an array.

PHP documentation for these functions:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: better answer than mine. use it... =]

Comment: Hey there, thank you for your reply! However, `$filename` would output as `ab1_cd2_ef3` and exclude the `.php`. So to revise your answer it would be: `$splitfilename = explode('_', $filename);`. This was exactly what i was looking for, thank you so much!

Comment: Aah, I'm glad I could help, I'll ammend my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
$file = __FILE__;
$arr = split("_",$file);
$arr[$arr.length-1] = split(".",$arr[$arr.length-1]);
$arr[$arr.length-1] = $arr[$arr.length-1][0];
```

did not test.. im working on it..

What i generally did is split by "_";
then i split "ef3.php" into [0]="ef3" [1]="php";
so i replace ef3.php with ef3

Comment: splitting . at the beginning makes more sense

Comment: Your answer is a solution that works in PHP4 at least. Pathinfo's `PATHINFO_FILENAME` constant was added in 5.2, so, kudos.